# No provider for shared component

Tags: angular, typescript

My app has several feature modules which use a few common `@Component`s.  So I wwas trying to move all those shared components in to a '[Widget Module](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#widget-feature-module)` as described by the angular.io FAQ linked [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#widget-feature-module).

However when I try to add this widget to one of my templates, I'm getting:

```
Error in package:./src/app/tracker/clients/client-detail.component.ts 
class ClientDetailComponent - inline template:28:8 caused by: 
No provider for String!
```

Here is where I try to use that shared component within the feature module:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'client-detail',
  template: `
<save-button id="save-button" (click)="saveClient()" [isSaving]="isSaving" [disableSave]="disableSave"></save-button>
`
})
export class ClientDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  isSaving: boolean = false;
  disableSave: boolean = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  saveClient() {
    this.isSaving = true;
    // do some work...
    this.isSaving = false;
}
```

Here's the feature module module:

```
import {SharedWidgetModule} from "../shared/shared-widget.module";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    TrackerRoutingModule,
    SharedWidgetModule
  ], declarations: [
    TrackerComponent,
    TrackerHomeComponent,

    // Clients
    ClientsComponent,
    ClientsHomeComponent,
    ClientShieldComponent,
    ClientDetailComponent,

    // EndClients
    EndClientListComponent
  ], providers: [
    BackendService,
    ClientsService
  ]
})
export class TrackerModule { }
```

The `<save-button>` component comes from the SharedWidgetModule:

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {SaveButtonComponent} from "./save-button/save-button.component";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    exports: [SaveButtonComponent, CommonModule],
    declarations: [SaveButtonComponent],
    providers: [],
})
export class SharedWidgetModule { }
```

save-button.component.html:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="disableSave || isSaving">
    <i *ngIf="isSaving" class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>
    <i *ngIf="!isSaving" class="fa {{icon}}"></i>
    {{name}}
</button>
```

save-button.component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'save-button',
    templateUrl: 'save-button.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./save-button.component.scss']
})
export class SaveButtonComponent implements OnInit {
    name: string;
    icon: string;
    @Input() isSaving: boolean;
    @Input() disableSave: boolean;

    constructor(name: string, icon: string) {
        this.name = name || 'Save';
        this.icon = icon || 'fa-floppy-o';
    }

    ngOnInit() { }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies on the `constructor` of `SaveButtonComponent`. For those Angular2 elements (`Component`, `Directive`, `Injectable`, etc.), constructor is a sacred place that should not be contaminated by mere primitives. Put it another way, Angular2 will try to inject services to your components using the information in its constructor, and clearly `name` and `icon` are not services.

I see that you are not using them at the moment, why don't you just get rid of those primitives and leave your `SavebuttonComponent.constructor()` empty? You can always set them up at later stage.

Comment: That was it, exactly.  I changed those to `@Input()`'s and no all is well.  Thanks for pointing out the obvious.  Sometimes the obvious is the hardest to see.